# Strategy for creating N number nested loops in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion

Suppose I have this pattern:

```
for(let i =0; i < 3; i++){
  for(let j =0; j < 3; j++){
    for(let k =0; k < 3; k++){
      console.log(i,j,k)
    }
  }
}
```

Benefit is I have access to all iteration variables within innermost loop. `i`, `j`, and `k`, disadvantage is it is hardcoded to 3 levels of nested loops. If I want a fourth I need to add that code manually.

I am trying to generalize the code using recursion where I can set the number of nested loops to an arbitrary variable. Here is what I am trying:

```
const maxNestedLoops = 3;
const iterations = 3;

const indexes = [];

function looper(loopNumber){  
  for(indexes[loopNumber] = 0; indexes[loopNumber] < iterations; indexes[loopNumber]++){

     if(loopNumber < maxNestedLoops){
      looper(loopNumber + 1);
     }
      console.log(indexes);

  }
}

looper(0);
```

The first results in the following in the console:

```
0, 0, 0
0, 0, 1
0, 0, 2
0, 1, 0
0, 1, 1
0, 1, 2
0, 2, 0
0, 2, 1
0, 2, 2
...and so on
```

However with my recursive function example it is not the same:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 3]
[0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 2]
[0, 0, 1, 3]
[0, 0, 2, 0]
[0, 0, 2, 1]
[0, 0, 2, 2]
[0, 0, 2, 3]
[0, 0, 3, 3]
...and so on
```

Problems are that not only are there four indexes instead of three. But some of the values are `3`s and I would expect it to only go up to `2`.

Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that:

- your `console.log` should only be executed at the deepest level. So put that `console.log` in an `else` clause.
- The base case happens when `loopNumber === maxNestedLoops - 1` as that is the last index of your array, so the `if` condition should correspond to that

```
     if (loopNumber < maxNestedLoops - 1){
         looper(loopNumber + 1);
     } else {
         console.log(indexes);
     }
```

Comment: That get's rid of the `3`s showing up in the output. But I still `.length` of 4  on that indexes array when I think I should be getting 3

Comment: Try `return looper(...` instead of  `looper(...`

Comment: `indexes` have to be 4, because it depends of number of loops

Comment: WillD, for that you should change the test, as indexes run to the array size - 1. Updated answer.

Comment: If the loopNumber is maxNestedLoops - 1 (in this example 2), you run the function again with increased loopNumber. That means you run it with loopNumber = 3 and this is extending the array to length of 4 (since indexes[3] points to forth element in array).

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, did you try that `return looper(....`?

Answer (score 1):

There is problem with the `for` loop. `indexes[loopNumber]++` will be increased   until it will reach the value of `iterations`. Since your value of iterations is `3`, you will end up with values which are equal to `3` in the `indexes` array, because the loop itself is modifying the array.

Also, since you modify your array if indexes before checking if the `loopNumber` reached the number of `maxNestedLoops`, you will end up with an array with length of `maxNestedLoops + 1`.

What I suggest you should do:

```js
const maxNestedLoops = 3;
const iterations = 3;

const indexes = [];

function looper(loopNumber) {
  // Check if we reached the number of nested loops before doing anything else.
  if (loopNumber < maxNestedLoops) {
    // Don't modify the indexes array directly, use a variable instead
    for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
      indexes[loopNumber] = i;
      looper(loopNumber + 1);
      console.log(indexes);
    }
  }
}

looper(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. It was a interesting one :)

```
const maxNestedLoops = 3;
const iterations = 3;

const indexes = [];

function looper(level){
    for (let i=0; i<iterations; i++){
        indexes.push(i);
        if (level === maxNestedLoops-1) {

            console.log(indexes);

            indexes.splice(level,1);
            continue;
        }

        looper(level + 1);
        indexes.splice(level,1);
    }
}

looper(0);
```